# JQuery load event on images

Tags: jquery, image, load, handler

I want to resize an image parent to the same size of the image, when the images are loaded.

At this time i'm using this code:

```
$(window).load(function(){
    $('.image-principale').each(function(){
        $(this).parent().css('height', $(this).height());
    });
});
```

It work, except than it runs only when *every* image has loaded.
I tried to add an load handler to every image directly but they doesn't trigger.

What's wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: You want it to run for each image as they load?

Comment: Yes, each image having a specific class

Answer (score 5):

Try the following:

```
...Your HTML...

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.image-principale').load(function(){
        $(this).parent().css('height', $(this).height());
    });
</script>
```

Note that the script must be placed after the HTML, or it will run before the `<img>` elements exist and will not actually do anything.

You could also try using `live`, like this:

```
$('.image-principale').live('load', function(){
    $(this).parent().css('height', $(this).height());
});
```

However, I don't know whether it will actually work.

Comment: You're quite right: putting the handler in ready() doesn't make sense in this case so you should put the JS after the HTML so +1 from me. Also, click on the votes thing, you currently have 1 up, 0 down. There was no downvote.

Comment: There was, but it was removed.

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't work.  I want to bind an load event to every matched element AFTER document ready but BEFORE window load.

Comment: Why do you need it to be after document ready?  Putting it after the HTML should be good enough.

Comment: It's just cleaner to have the js at the same place. Correct me if i'm wrong but using the $(document).ready or putting the js at the end of the page produce the sames result.

Comment: No, `$(document).ready` waits for **all** of the resources to be ready. Putting at the end will just wait until everything has been created in the DOM (including the `img` tags).

Comment: From the jQuery doc. Event ready: Specify a function to execute when the DOM is fully loaded.

Answer (score 2):

On document ready is easy:

```
$(function() {
  $('.image-principale').load(function(){
    $(this).parent().css('height', $(this).height());
  });
});
```

or even:

```
$(function() {
  $('.image-principale').live('load', function(){
    $(this).parent().css('height', $(this).height());
  });
});
```

outside or inside `ready()`.

Answer (score 2):

Basically, you want to listen to load or readystatechange events from the img element.

So you need to do this:

```
$(window).load(function(){
    $('.image-principale img').on("load readystatechange", function(){
        // Here you can check whether it state complete by checking 
        // if(this.complete || (this.readyState == 'complete' && e.type == 'readystatechange') ) { }
        $(this).parent().css('height', $(this).height());
    });
});
```

But... this way have a few ( big ) caveats. Namely that it will not "always" work, and it will not work with "cache" images ( sometimes ). 
The best way is actually an extent of the code above ( that will check some more conditions that are quite hard to check ) from Desandro, a library called [jquery.imagesLoaded](https://github.com/desandro/imagesloaded)

It will check for loading events, and some more conditions ( like broken images, cached images, loaded element, ... ) and gives you a feedback when ALL elements are loaded.

Usage is ( you can see more on the website ) :

```
// Loading script 
var dfd = $('#my-container').imagesLoaded(function($images, $proper, $broken){
    //Here you can do a loop on $proper that is the list of images that properly loaded.
}); // save a deferred object and use dfd later
```

You can also have, for every image loaded, a callback:

```
dfd.progress(function( isBroken, $images, $proper, $broken ){ });
```

I'm quite sure this will solve your ( very old... sorry ) problem. I  post it here as it could help some other people.

Answer (score 1):

Works for me: http://jsbin.com/ululo/edit

```
$(function(){
  $("img").load(function(){
    $(this).parent().height( $(this).height() ); 
  }); 
});
```

Comment: That's because JSBin emits the script after the HTML; he put the script before the HTML.  See my answer.

Comment: Thats what I need, but it doesnt work with more than one image

Comment: @Jonathan: it doesn't work here.. rev 5 on jsbin. I'm using FF 3.6

Comment: @Hubert: I just tried it in FF 3.5.7 and it worked just fine. Progressively loaded each image, and then resized their wrapper to be their height.

Comment: @Jonathan: Oh I got it working by clearing my cache. Actually it work but only the first time. When the image are cached the load event won't trigger. Any ideas?

Comment: @Hubert: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2392410/jquery-loading-images-with-complete-callback

Answer (score 1):

$('img').load seems to fire each time the image resizes. In my case it makes my site slow. (I'm tried it on FF)