# JQuery Image load fails on MobiOne iPhone simulator

Tags: jquery, mobile-website, jqtouch, iphone, mobione

I dynamically update an image on a JQTouch site using the following code:

```
  $('#sv_map')
            .one('load', function() {
                $(this).fadeIn();
            })
            .attr('src', imgURL);
```

Got the basics of this from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2392410/jquery-loading-images-with-complete-callback). `sv_map` is an image, and `imgURL` points to a valid, existing JPG file.

This code works as expected on all major browsers (Chrome, Safari, Firefox, IE) as well as on actual devices (several iPhones and iPods).

I don't want to conclude that the simulator has a bug (it seems like such a trivial issue). What additional code is needed to ensure that the image file gets loaded? Has anyone had a similar experience with MobiOne?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not all browsers fire the `load` event correctly (especially when loading from cache), so you'll need to do it manually by checking `.complete` on the image, like this:

```
  $('#sv_map').one('load', function() {
               $(this).fadeIn();
            }).attr('src', imgURL)
              .each(function() {
               if(this.complete) $(this).load();
            });
```

Comment: Worked for me too! +2 for you