# How to Bind Load event for Image in jQueryMobile

Tags: iphone, ios-simulator, jquery-mobile

I have a mobile website running jQuery Mobile 1.0a2 and I'm currently testing in Mobile Safari for Firmware 4.1 via the iPhone Simulator.

**I cannot seem to bind to the load event for an image.**

I have a simple gallery of thumbnails and a large image. When you click on a thumbnail it changes the `src` attribute of the main `img`

The js for that uses the `live('click'` method to bind and it works just fine.

```
$('.gallery-navigation img').live('click',function() {
  // change source of main image to new
  $.mobile.pageLoading(); // show jquerymobile loading message
});
```

My problem is that I need feedback on this click, so I wanted to show a loading message (provided by jquerymobile) and then hide it once the image loads.

Where `#gallery_image_large` is the actual `<img>` where the `src` is changing, I tried the following:

```
$("#gallery_image_large").bind("load", function () {
   $.mobile.pageLoading(true); // hide jquerymobile loading message
});
```

This works in Safari on my desktop but does not in the iPhone Simulator mentioned above.

*For reference:*

- [jQuery Mobile Loading Message Methods](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a2/#docs/api/methods.html)

**UPDATE:** I am experimenting with [JQuery Image load fails on MobiOne iPhone simulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3256306/jquery-image-load-fails-on-mobione-iphone-simulator), which explains how to implement the `.load` manually by "checking `.complete`".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed the structure of my jquery and it's seemed to have fixed it!

```
$('#gallery_image_large').one('load',function() {
    try { // a grade  
        $.mobile.pageLoading(true);
    } catch(err) { // low grade

    }
}).attr('src',full_src);
```

(as you can see, I opt'd for a `try { .. } catch { .. }` to verify jquerymobile is available.

Although I didn't use the solution (directly) from [JQuery Image load fails on MobiOne iPhone simulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3256306/jquery-image-load-fails-on-mobione-iphone-simulator), the manual firing of `load` via `.complete` is probably a good solution for anyone else out there!