# Wait until all images are loaded after changing their src

Tags: jquery, html, css

I've got project in which after document is fully loaded I have to change images src attributes (fix them a little bit).

What I would like to have is the option to check whether all images after thier src attribute is changed are fully loaded so that I can then calculate their height and based on that proceed with my code.

Is this possible ?

Comment: out of curiosity... what do you mean with "fix them a little bit". If you change the src, that could cause another image to be loaded. Just wanted to be sure that's what you're looking for.

Comment: thats right, replace images with new ones and then how to be sure when all of them are fully loaded

Answer (score 4):

You can do with jQuery:

```
$('img#newsrc').load(function(){  // this triggers after image is loaded

    // do your checking

}
```

Or a specific image:

```
var file = 'beautiful.jpg';
$('img').attr('src', file).load(function() {  
    alert(file + 'is loaded');  
});
```

Comment: the document is fully loaded, then I change src of all images, then I want to know when new images are fully loaded.

Comment: OK I get you. You could use $('img').load(function()

Comment: use $('img').load(function(): doesnt work... not always good result

Comment: This might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2392410/jquery-loading-images-with-complete-callback

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do something after ALL the images on the page are loaded try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var nImages = $('img').length;
  $('img').load(function () {
    nImages--;
    if (nImages == 0) {
      ... do whatever ...
    }
  }
});
```

If you don't want to include all the images, just change the selector 'img' to something more specific.