# How to start a function when background image loads completely?

Tags: jquery

Hullo brothers!
I wanted to run a function when image loading completes. My code:-

HTML:-

```
<div id="s_pc" style="background-image:url(http://www.surfixe.com/img/surfixe_pc.png)"></div>
<button id="btn" style="display:none">This button should only show when image loading completes!</button>
```

jQuery:-

```
$('#s_pc').attr('style', 'background-image:url(www.surfixe.com/img/surfixe_pc.png)').load(function() {  
    alert('Image Loaded');
    $('#btn').show();
});
```

[My current fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Tomer123/rKSKF/3/)

Seems like there is an error in my coding. Any ideas?

Comment: Some searching: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2392410/jquery-loading-images-with-complete-callback

Answer (score 0):

try this. 
to load the image using Javascript, and then set that image as the backgroud.

```
var bgImg = new Image();
bgImg.onload = function(){
   $('#s_pc').css('background-image', 'url(www.surfixe.com/img/surfixe_pc.png)');
    alert('Image Loaded');
    $('#btn').show();
};
bgImg.src = 'www.surfixe.com/img/surfixe_pc.png'；
```

Comment: sorry, but this code does not work

Comment: you need some cleanup.. such as the current src..

Answer (score -1):

Some one here (I don't know the name) has answered my question but deleted it. So, I thought I should post it:-

```
$('<img/>').attr('src', 'http://www.surfixe.com/img/surfixe_pc.png').load(function() {
    alert('Image Loaded');
    $('#btn').show();
});
```

edit: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Tomer123/rKSKF/5/)

Comment: This is not the answer to what you originally asked.

Comment: What do u mean? This code worked perfectly