# Load image background with fadeIn() effect

Tags: jquery, css, background, fadein

I'm trying to show a div background with `fadein()` effect when it completes loading.

I've been searching and the closer I got was [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2392410/jquery-loading-images-with-complete-callback) (wich works great on a `<img>` tag).

I want to do exactly the same with the css background property of a div. Here is the code I'm tryin' to work:

**HTML**

```
<div id="some_target"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
#some_target {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%; height: 100% ;      
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var newImage = "url(http://vanusasousa.com.br/sicom/img/background2.jpg)"; //Image name

  $("#some_target").hide() //Hide it
    .one('load', function() { //Set something to run when it finishes loading
      $(this).fadeIn(); //Fade it in when loaded
    })
    .css('background', newImage) //Set the background image
    .each(function() {
      //Cache fix for browsers that don't trigger .load()
      if(this.complete) $(this).trigger('load');
    });   
});
```

---

It looks fine to me, except that doesn't work. [Here is the jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DfFhp/1/) I'm working at.

Does anyone know what am I doing wrong?

Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.load` and `.complete` do not apply to divs.  Just create an `<img>` and use its triggers to properly update the div.

```
var newImage = "http://vanusasousa.com.br/sicom/img/background2.jpg";
$("#some_target").hide().css('background', 'url(' + newImage + ')');
var $img = $("<img>").attr('src', newImage).one('load', function () {
    $("#some_target").fadeIn();
});
if ($img.get(0).complete) {
    $("#some_target").fadeIn();
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/DfFhp/2/

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Could you please just tell if in that case, once the `background` is loaded that way If I use it in another page on my system if it will be loaded again? Or the browser caches it? Thank you very much!

Comment: @Christian browser will probably cache it; depends on the browser of course