# jquery detect when specific (external) image has loaded

Tags: jquery, iframe

When loading an iframe with a youtube clip in it, the very last file that comes in from youtube is this image:

http://i1.ytimg.com/vi/W6YOAlxT7Ls/hqdefault.jpg

I'd like to fire a function when that specific image is done loading. How can I detect
this w/jquery?

I've tried this:

```
$('[![][1]][1]').on('load', function() { 
    // bam
});
```

...but it results in a reload of the same image. I don't need to fetch the image, I just need to know when it has been fetched.

Christ. Even this results in the image being re-fetched:

```
$.when($('[![][1]][1]').load()).then( bam() );
```

Comment: maybe `$('[src="http://i1.ytimg.com/vi/W6YOAlxT7Ls/hqdefault.jpg"]').on(...)` will help

Comment: possibly duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2392410/jquery-loading-images-with-complete-callback

Comment: Yep. Using [src=""] solved it; thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
$('<img src="http://i1.ytimg.com/vi/W6YOAlxT7Ls/hqdefault.jpg"/>').one('load', function () {
        //your code to fire when image has loaded 
    }).each(function () {
        if (this.complete) $(this).load();
    });
```

Comment: This too really helps because of the inconsistency of .load; thank you.