# Show image only after fully loaded

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to hide an image until it fully loads.

I've this `jquery`.

```
//Load image on click
$(document).on("click", '[data-item="zoomIn"]', function(){
     var url = $(this).parent().siblings('.largeImgUrl').val();
     $('.flickr-big-image').empty().append("<img class='hidden' id='zoomIn' src='"+url+"' >");
     $("#flickr-popup").modal('show');
});

//Show image            
$('#zoomIn').on('load', function(){
    $('#zoomIn').removeClass('hidden');
});
```

But it seems the `onload` event is not functioning. Am I doing it wrong here?

Comment: You need to trigger on the loading of the image and not the html. have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2392410/jquery-loading-images-with-complete-callback

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#zoomIn').on('load', function(){
        $('#zoomIn').removeClass('hidden');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are calling

```
$('#zoomIn').on('load', function(){
    $('#zoomIn').removeClass('hidden');
});
```

before the item "zoomIn" is appended.

If you do:

```
//Load image on click
$(document).on("click", '[data-item="zoomIn"]', function(){
     var url = $(this).parent().siblings('.largeImgUrl').val();
     $('.flickr-big-image').empty().append("<img class='hidden' id='zoomIn' src='"+url+"' >");

     $('#zoomIn').on('load', function(){
         $('#zoomIn').removeClass('hidden');
     });

     $("#flickr-popup").modal('show');
});
```

It will work