# jQuery: how to get height of image div in dialog window if that height changes after image load from server?

Tags: jquery

Here is html code:

```
<div id="image-div">
    <img id="image" src="" />
</div>
```

And js code:

```
# on dialog open
$.ajax({
    url: "/ajax/img",
    success: function(data){
        $("#image").prop("src", data);
    }
});
```

So, at the beginning the height of `#image-div` = 0 and it changes only after real image loaded from server (after success ajax request). How to get new height of that div?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the load event for the image. I have seen some alternate solutions because for cached images `load` may not fire. Honestly I've never seen this on my own sites. I have also seen on SO someone say that `$('#image').ready( function() { ... });` has always worked for them.

```
success: function(data){
        $("#image").prop("src", data).load( function() {
               $(this).parent('div').height();
        });
    }
```

Ahh, dug up the link to the 'ultra safe way' for detecting image load.

[Image does not have width at document.ready](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7587714/image-does-not-have-width-at-document-ready/7587748#7587748)